# Python 3 and Tkinter. Too many global variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I started programming a simple GUI application in Python, using Tkinter library.
Everything works fine but, to dynamically change any widget (for example a button from "login" to "logout", etc), I have to get the variable containing the widget object itself in the function from outside.
I can do this in two ways:

1. passing the widget as a argument;
2. using global variables.

A simplified example:

1) Passing as argument:

```
def changeLabel(b):
    b.config(text='Logout')

btn1 = Button(f0,text="Login",width=15)
btn1.grid(row=1,column=2,rowspan=1,padx=10,ipadx=10)
changeLabel(btn1)
```

2) Or using a global variable:

```
def changeLabel():
    global btn1
    btn1.config(text='Logout')

btn1 = Button(f0,text="Login",width=15)
btn1.grid(row=1,column=2,rowspan=1,padx=10,ipadx=10)
changeLabel(btn1)
```

Now, I know that *global variables should be avoided* but passing every widget as argument through many functions, even in a simple application, it's a mess.

So, what's the best way to manipulate the Tkinter widgets at runtime? Can you suggest me the right way?
Thank you

Comment: Can't you just not have a `changeLabel` function at all, and do `btn1.config(text="Logout")` inline? Incidentally, the `global` statement isn't needed in approach #2, because you're not assigning anything to `btn1`.

Comment: A third option is to use classes, where the widget is an attribute of the class.

Comment: My example is voluntary simplified, in my application I need to:
- hide a button and show another one
- change text every click
- hide/show frames
- et cetera...

Comment: @Kevin: I would say that calling a function is a best practice. Inlining code like that makes for a program that is harder to maintain over time.

Comment: BTW, you're _already_ importing over 130 names into your global namespace because you do `from tkinter import *`. It's far better to do `import tkinter as tk`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to manipulate tkinter widgets at runtime is to store those widgets as attributes of a class.

For example:

```
class Example(...):
    def create_widgets(self):
        ...
        self.btn1 = Button(...)
        ...
    def changeLabel(self):
        self.bt1.config(...)
```

For more information see [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application)